# Identify a woody plant from Eastern Missouri that causes a skin rash

Tags: identification

[image]

These are woody multiple leaved plants that look like vines but are not. They volunteer themselves among my garden beds. They have deep roots and must be removed with a shovel. If I so much as look their direction I break out in a rash. What is it? Eastern Missouri if that helps.

Comment: Is this all one plant? I see two different growth habits and leaf shapes here. One upright with alternate leaves and reddish stems, the other spreading with paired leaves and greenish stems. The leaves might be a slightly different shape too: the ones on the green stems look a little narrower than those on the red stems.

Comment: Does the rash break out immediately or can it take a day or two? Is it like pustules full of liquid or kind of a brownish or reddish patchy rash, with llarge blisters? If brownish or reddish and blistered, does it only occur on sunny days?

Both plants have a passing resemblance to poison sumac (which was my immediate thought), but the leaves on each are wrong - there should be a terminal leaflet and I don't see one on either plant.

Comment: This is in a bed of ornamental grass - lirope. The rash appears days later even after washing with Technu after exposure. It starts out like a scratch and spreads like a burn. My guess was also sumac, but stems not red, leaves not glossy and no berries.

Comment: 0
down vote
 

Are you absolutely sure that you're being affected by one of these shrubs? The plant with the smaller, lanceolate leaves looks like some kind of honeysuckle (Lonicera spp.). A weed, for sure. The other shrub resembles a poplar (Populus spp.) - not saying it is a poplar, however. Your rash sounds more photo-chemical than anything else - does the rash result in a pigmentation change in the skin that persists for weeks or months?